# Aggregate count of strings that contain substring in a series

Tags: pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['John', 'Felix', 'Vicki', 'Sam', 'Jack', 'Rodney'], 
'col2': ['Likes tea with cookies', 'Likes tea with croissants','Likes coffee with churros',
'Likes tea with muffins','Likes beer with chicken wings','Likes coffee with donuts']})

In [4]:df1
Out[4]: 
     col1                           col2
0    John         Likes tea with cookies
1   Felix      Likes tea with croissants
2   Vicki      Likes coffee with churros
3     Sam          Likes tea with muffins
4    Jack  Likes beer with chicken wings
5  Rodney       Likes coffee with donuts
```

When I get the `value_counts()` for items in `col2`, I get the count for each string in the series. As expected, each string is unique, occurs only once and the count is 1 for each:

```
In [5]: df1['col2'].value_counts()
Out[5]: 
Likes coffee with churros        1
Like tea with muffins            1
Likes tea with croissants        1
Likes coffee with donuts         1
Likes beer with chicken wings    1
Likes tea with cookies           1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

**What I'd like to do is**: aggregate the `value_counts()` for strings that contain similar substrings such as `Likes tea with..` and `Likes coffee with..` and show me an output like this:

```
Likes coffee with     2
Likes tea with        3
Likes beer with       1
```

My dataframe has many rows with similar strings (with just slight differences) in a column and I've been trying to club the ones which contain a substring and return `value_counts()` with the aggregated count of such strings and the counts of other strings as well in the column.

**My attempt**: I can get the count of the occurrence of a substring like this:

```
In [14]:df1['col2'].str.lower().str.count("likes tea with").sum()
Out[14]: 2
```

But this only gives me the individual count of the occurrence of a particular substring.

**Question**: How do I get all counts in one output, with the aggregated count of similar looking strings(such as in my example) alongwith the counts of all the other strings?

Comment: Is "Like tea" a typo or would you really want to group "Like tea" with "Likes tea"?

Comment: Yes, its a typo..I've changed that. But even with the typo, I'd like to club them together, because my dataframe contains strings in both singular and plural forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the column and apply value_counts by eliminating the last word

```
df1.col2 = df1.col2.replace('Like ', 'Likes ', regex = True)
df1['col2'].str.split().str[:-1].apply(' '.join).value_counts()

Likes tea with             3
Likes coffee with          2
Likes beer with chicken    1
```